# Rails count of distinct values of a column of associated model in SQL

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have in my Rails (4.1.8) app the following models: `Event, User, Box, EventBoxMapping` and following associations relevant to the question among them:

```
User has_many events; Event belogs_to User
Event has_many boxes through event_box_mappings
```

I'm trying to achieve faster (and hopefully more memory efficient) CSV generation through ActiveAdmin by using PostgreSQL's **COPY** functionality to stream output of a raw SQL directly into a CSV export. To achieve this, however, I need to pass a raw SQL string, which I'm having some trouble creating for all bits of information generated to populate columns of our Events CSV. In particular, I'd like to pick out **counts of distinct values** of `box_property_id` column of the boxes of events.

Now, so far, I have the following SQL that runs perfectly to maps some values of Event and User models:

```
SELECT 
    events.id, 
    events.user_id, 
    events.event_type, 
    events.promo_code, 
    events.created_at, 
    events.transport_fee, 
    events.boxes_count, 
    users.email, 
    users.gender, 
    users.first_name, 
    users.last_name 
FROM events 
LEFT JOIN users ON users.id = events.user_id`
```

I'm stuck at the part I mentioned above - to include counts of "each kind of box" represented by the `box_property_id` field in boxes of an Event in the table returned by the above SQL.

I come from a NoSQL background from past experience and fairly new to this field, and so I apologise if my query is ambiguous/incomplete in some form.

Comment: Fast question, I didn't understand, do you need to count box_property_id from the above statement or? Since I can't see the box_property_id anywhere in the statement you wrote, if this is the case I can write you simple SQL to count the field. Also, where is box_property_id field ? Which table has that value and how is it connected to the others?

Comment: I would suggest you leave out unnecessary information. You talk about wanting to COPY it to CSV. But that's irrelevant because you're asking for help with a query. Don't give background that's unnecessary in order to understand the question. (I'm saying this because I spent some time wondering what about it was incompatible with COPY... then realised it had nothing to do with it.)

Comment: Quick question. Is `EventBoxMapping` belongs_to `Event` and `Box`?

Answer (score 1):

As understood, you need you wanna get distinct count of `box_property_id` with other columns.

```
Event.joins(:user, event_box_mappings: :box)
     .select("events.id, events.user_id, events.event_type, events.promo_code,
             events.created_at, events.transport_fee, events.boxes_count, 
             users.email, users.gender, users.first_name, users.last_name,
             COUNT(distinct boxes.box_property_id) AS total")
```

`total` will return the count of distinct `box_property_id`.

Hope this would be helpful